# What is a Regular Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

If a word has a certain property, I call it a ***Regular Word™***.

You can use the examples below to find the property:

| Regular™ | Not Regular™ |
| --- | --- |
| NAP | SLEEP |
| AXED | FIRED |
| QUIT | EXIT |
| WHIZ | GENIUS |
| DEATH | EXPIRY |
| GREEK | LATIN |
| BOXING | FIGHTING |
| KIDNAP | ABDUCT |
| OBJECT | THING |
| REVIEW | PERUSE |
| SPHINX | RIDDLER |
| HEXAGON | PENTAGON |
| MOSQUES | TEMPLES |
| FEMINISM | EQUALITY |
| LUXURIANT | LAVISH |
| CONTEXTUAL | RELATED |
| EXCAVATION | DIGGING |
| JUXTAPOSES | OVERLAPS |
| PERPLEXITY | CONFUSION |
| INTOXICATES | INEBRIATES |

Here is a CSV version:

```
Regular™,Not Regular™
NAP,SLEEP
AXED,FIRED
QUIT,EXIT
WHIZ,GENIUS
DEATH,EXPIRY
GREEK,LATIN
BOXING,FIGHTING
KIDNAP,ABDUCT
OBJECT,THING
REVIEW,PERUSE
SPHINX,RIDDLER
HEXAGON,PENTAGON
MOSQUES,TEMPLES
FEMINISM,EQUALITY
LUXURIANT,LAVISH
CONTEXTUAL,RELATED
EXCAVATION,DIGGING
JUXTAPOSES,OVERLAPS
PERPLEXITY,CONFUSION
INTOXICATES,INEBRIATES
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand what exactly I have to solve.

Comment: @BlackPanda all the Regular words share a specific property/pattern which is not valid for the Not Regular words. You can look at older puzzles tagged word-property (click on the tag) for examples.

Comment: @BlackPanda Read the [tag wiki](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/word-property/info) about [tag:word-property].

Comment: Oh okay, so I had to define what a regular word is. Anyway it's solved. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Regular Word™ is a word in which

> The length of the word is the same as the distance between the first and last letters in the alphabet.
>
>  In other words, the number of letters between the first and last letters of the word is also the number of letters between them in the alphabet.

for example

> "MOSQUES" has the same number of letters as "MNOPQRS," and "EXCAVATION" has the same number of letters as "EFGHIJKLMN"

Comment: I'm curious how you found the solution

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain It started coming together for me when I noticed that Regular Words ended with letters that came after their starting letter (there was also the misguided but coincidentally helpful observation that N+A=P). It would have been interesting if words such as `VELVETEEN`, `SHARPSHOOTING`, and `RIBONUCLEOTIDE` were also Regular Words - I'm not sure I would have figured it out if they were.