# What is an Absolute Word?™

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Absolute Word™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Absolute Words™ | Not Absolute Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| WET | DRY |
| MUNICIPALITY | DISTRICT |
| ADVERTORIAL | COMMERCIAL |
| HAND | FOOT |
| NAUGHT | ZERO |
| TRAINSPOTTING | ECSTASY |
| CINEMATOGRAPHER | PHOTOGRAPHER |
| GRASSHOPPER | CRICKET |
| VOLLEYBALL | BADMINTON |
| ITALIC | BOLD |
| UNICORN | DRAGON |
| EXCEPTION | RULE |
| PERSPECTIVE | VIEW |
| JOURNALIST | CORRESPONDENT |
| ACHE | PAIN |
| MATCH | CONTEST |
| OUTGOING | EXTROVERT |
| CATHEDRAL | CHURCH |

In case you want it in CSV:

```
Absolute Words™,Not Absolute Words™
WET,DRY  
MUNICIPALITY,DISTRICT  
ADVERTORIAL,COMMERCIAL  
HAND,FOOT  
NAUGHT,ZERO  
TRAINSPOTTING,ECSTASY  
CINEMATOGRAPHER,PHOTOGRAPHER
GRASSHOPPER,CRICKET
VOLLEYBALL,BADMINTON
ITALIC,BOLD
UNICORN,DRAGON
EXCEPTION,RULE
PERSPECTIVE,VIEW
JOURNALIST,CORRESPONDENT
ACHE,PAIN
MATCH,CONTEST
OUTGOING,EXTROVERT
CATHEDRAL,CHURCH
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Absolute Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of Absolute Words™, many more exist.

Hint:

> Ordering the words in an obvious way (both alphabetical and by word length could prove helpful) might help you spot the rule.

Hint 2:

> Think of "absolute" in a mathematical way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A word is an Absolute Word if

> its length equals the (absolute) distance apart in the alphabet of the letters at its ends.

(There was another word-property puzzle with a very similar answer: [What is a Regular Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42947/what-is-a-regular-word))

Comment: +1 for the right catch of the similar one. Still not sure how do you see puzzles :D

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. Turns out to be harder than I thought to come with something original..

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. There have been an awful lot of these and no one can be expected to have memorized them all. (And yours was a little different.)